# How do I access a member inside another member of NSDictionary while keeping a link between members

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

`NSDictionary` confuses me. It is somewhat like a hybrid of a struct and an array from what I gather. I'm going through the iOS Programming book and it has us put a JSON object into an `NSDictionary`. All is fine for objects with the key "titles" to return, but for `upcoming` classes there are variables inside `upcoming`. In my head this is how the `NSDictionary` would be built.

```
struct classes {
    NSString *title;
    struct upcoming[] {
        NSString *end_date;
        NSString *start_date;
        NSString *instructor;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to retrieve the `start_date`'s inside a `for` loop by using variations of:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [course objectForKey:@"upcoming.start_date"]);
```

The purpose of me doing this is to append the string of `title`'s that have a value inside `upcoming` classes with their `start_date`. Something like...

```
NSString *value = course[@"title"];
if ([course objectForKey@"upcoming"] [value stringByAppendingString:
                                         @" course[@"upcoming.start_date"];
NSLog(@"%@", value);
```

**How do I make it so that IF there IS one or more values for `upcoming` then it will display those start_date values by appending the string displayed ELSE it won't do anything?** Obviously `upcoming.start_date` is not the way to do it! and `start_date` by itself has no link to the relevant `title`. I need them both to be linked to append the appropriate string.

Solution:

```
NSString *title = [course objectForKey:@"title"];
NSArray *upcomingCourses = [course objectForKey:@"upcoming"];
if (upcomingCourses.count > 0
    NSString *showDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. Next Class Date: %@"
    title, [[upcomingCourses objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"start_date"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", showDate);
}
else NSLog(@"%@", title);
```

Posted `NSDictionary` from `NSLog`:

```
courses =     (
            {
        title = "Advanced iOS Bootcamp";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-04-04";
                instructors = Blocksom;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-03-31";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-05-16";
                instructors = Dalrymple;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-05-12";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-20";
                instructors = Ward;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-16";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/advanced-ios-bootcamp";
    },
            {
        title = "Beginning iOS (iPhone/iPad)";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-04-18";
                instructors = Mathias;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-04-12";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-05-02";
                instructors = "Keur, Ward";
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-04-26";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-05-23";
                instructors = Christopher;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-05-17";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-06";
                instructors = Christopher;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-05-31";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-07-25";
                instructors = Ritchie;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-19";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-08-01";
                instructors = "Usiyan, Keur";
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-26";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-09-19";
                instructors = Ritchie;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-09-13";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/beginning-ios";
    },
            {
        title = "Mobile Design Bootcamp";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-13";
                instructors = "Harper, Porter";
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-09";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/mobile-design-bootcamp";
    },
            {
        title = "Python Programming";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-04-24";
                instructors = Cassell;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-04-21";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-19";
                instructors = Cassell;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-16";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/python-programming";
    },
            {
        title = "Beginning iOS Game Development";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-20";
                instructors = Strougo;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-16";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-09-26";
                instructors = Strougo;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-09-22";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/beginning-ios-game-development";
    },
            {
        title = "Android Bootcamp";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-05-16";
                instructors = Phillips;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-05-12";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-20";
                instructors = Marsicano;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-16";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-07-11";
                instructors = Stewart;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-07";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-10-03";
                instructors = Phillips;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-09-29";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/android-bootcamp";
    },
            {
        title = "HTML5 Apps with jQuery";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-05-16";
                instructors = Aquino;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-05-12";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-13";
                instructors = Gandee;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-09";
            },
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-08-01";
                instructors = Aquino;
                location = "BNR West, California";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-28";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/html5-apps-with-jquery";
    },
            {
        title = "Ruby on the Server";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-06-13";
                instructors = Stewart;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-06-09";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/ruby-on-the-server";
    },
            {
        title = "iOS Bootcamp - Fast Track";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-07-11";
                instructors = Usiyan;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-07";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/ios-bootcamp-fast-track";
    },
            {
        title = "Cocoa I Bootcamp";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-07-25";
                instructors = Preble;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-21";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/cocoa-i-bootcamp";
    },
            {
        title = "OpenGL ES Bootcamp";
        upcoming =             (
                            {
                "end_date" = "2014-07-25";
                instructors = Blocksom;
                location = "Atlanta, Georgia";
                "start_date" = "2014-07-21";
            }
        );
        url = "https://training.bignerdranch.com/classes/opengl-es-bootcamp";
    }
);
```

}

Comment: An `NSDictionary` is a mapping between a _set_ (no repeats) of keys and a collection of values. Depending on what other languages you're familiar with, its structure might be known to you as an "[associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)", "hash table", or "map". Each key corresponds to one value; they are paired, and the pairs are not ordered.

Comment: Can you put the actual construction or layout of your dictionary into the question? Printing it out via `NSLog()` will do.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Updated. It's long!

Comment: Before you do anything else, go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  While the Java folks like to over-complicate it by mapping it directly to structures, in fact, it's best envisioned as a "tree" of arrays and dictionaries (hashtables).  (And if you want to get anywhere with Objective-C you need to get VERY comfortable with NSArray and NSDictionary, since they handle about 80% of the data in applications.)

Comment: Note that in the above dump, the outermost "layer" (bracketed by the `()` characters) is an NSArray, the next layer in (bracketed by the `{}` characters) is an NSDictionary, then inside the dictionary are a couple of strings and another array (`()` again) which in turn contains more dictionaries.  The beauty of this scheme is that you can represent a data structure of relatively arbitrary structure with just those two simple objects -- NSArray and NSDictonary.  And that is also the beauty of JSON, since it's "array" and "object" map to the Objective-C structures nicely.

Comment: @HotLicks much appreciated. This and Paul's comments helped me understand immensely. Still looking it over, but I'm much less confused now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDictionary allows you to retrieve objects by key.  The key is just another object, but commonly NSStrings are used (the restriction being that keys must be unique, values do not need to be).  Any object can be stored under the key, so in your case 'upcoming' is an array of NSDictionaries.  So you get

```
dictionary {
   title: someString
   upcoming: array {
       0: dictionary {
          end_date: somestring
          start_date: someString
          instructor: someString
       }
       1: dictionary {
          end_date: somestring
          start_date: someString
          instructor: someString
       }
   }

}
```

Note that the above isn't any particular language or syntax, just a representation of the 'structure' of your data.

To retrieve the course details you would access the "upcoming" object just like any other and assign it to a variable.

Assuming `course` is your root `NSDictionary`:

```
NSString *title=(NSString *)[course objectForKey:@"title"];
NSArray *upcomingCourses=(NSArray *)[course objectForKey:@"upcoming"];

NSMutableString *startDates=[[NSMutablestring alloc]init];

for (int i=0;i<[upcomingCourses count];i++)
{  
    NSDictionary *upcomingCourse = (NSDictionary *)[upcomingCourses objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *startDate = (NSString *)[upcomingCourse objectForKey:@"start_date"];
    NSString *endDate = (NSString *)[upcomingCourse objectForKey:@"end_date"];
    NSString *instructor = (NSString *)[upcomingCourse objectForKey:@"instructor"];

    [startDates appendFormat:@"%@, ",startDate];
}
```

Comment: Could you show me some rough syntax of how you would add this to a ``for`` loop? Maybe I need to add the objects to an array to link them?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that upcoming was an array - let me revise my answer

Comment: Hmm, I think I will need to go back and study NSDictionary again. I'm not processing this at all. I am still expecting to see something like ``if (objectKey@"title" hasNonNullObject: objectKey@"upcoming") doSomething();`` I can't visualize how this would concatenate the strings.

Comment: upcoming will always have an object - an array - the array may have 0 entries.  The for loop in my answer handles this case because count will be 0 and 0 is not < 0 - so the loop will never execute.  I will update my answer to show concatenating the start dates

Comment: It's showing what I want it to show, I'm still playing with the code to understand it but you've given me a great push in the right direction. Thank you!